# Check browser width and execute a Javascript file and override another Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is an HTML file with many embedded YouTube videos.Page load times were slow so I decided to use this JS file to force the page load an image instead of iframe, until the user clicks on it. http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/youtube-video-embed-like-google-plus.html

CSS checks if the visitor uses mobile and optimizes the layout for mobile.I modified the above mentioned JS script to show smaller thumbnails so it will work better on mobile(no need to scroll horizontally).I have 2 version of that JS script now.

**The goal:** Check if visitor uses desktop.If yes, execute the regular gplus-youtubeembed.js.If visitor uses mobile then execute gplus-youtubeembed-**mobile**.js

This was the original HTML.It would only load the desktop version of JS.As a result, mobile visitors would see a very large video thumbnail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes">

<script src=gplus-youtubeembed.js></script>

<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media=screen />
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <h1>My First Heading</h1> 
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>

<script>optimizeYouTubeEmbeds()</script> <!--needed to load image instead of iframe-->

</body>

</html>
```

Then I used this method http://www.coalmarch.com/blog/how-to-execute-javascript-based-on-screen-size-using-jquery

```
if ( $(window).width() > 700) {      
  //added the content of gplus-youtubeembed.js here
} 
else {
  //added the content of gplus-youtubeembed-mobile.js here
}
```

I named that gplus-youtubeembed-combine.js and replaced gplus-youtubeembed.js with gplus-youtubeembed-combined.js , in the HTML doc.

**The outcome:** The only JS that gets executed is the mobile version.Desktop visitors see small thumbnails.Everyting works fine in mobile.Why doesn't the gplus-youtubeembed-combined.js work properly ? It's supposed to detect if the screen width is over 700 and execute the gplus-youtubeembed.js file but it doesn't.Any help is appreciated.Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed.When I copy/pasted two JS files into the if/else statement, something broke the "if" statement so "else" was always being executed.I confirmed this by swapping the mobile and desktop versions and changing ">" to "<".In that case only desktop version would load.

Instead of copy/pasting the entire JS files into else/if, I left the common part out and added only the portion that was different in desktop/mobile version.Sounds simple, but it didn't come to my mind at the beginning.

The author of the original JS did not provide the mobile friendly version of the JS so people who use that code on their website might benefit from this post.One issue with the below code is that on mobile version, the image doesn't have a play button.It only has a thumbnail so make sure the visitor knows it's a video.This can be fixed by further tweaking the code but that's another topic.

Working version.

gplus-youtubeembedded-combine.js

```
    // gplus-youtubeembed - Makes embedded YouTube video iframes Google+ style to improve page loading speed.
// Copyright (c) 2013 by Arun - http://www.skipser.com
// Licensed under the GNU LGPL license: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html
// For usage details, read - http://www.skipser.com/510

// Call this function at the end of the closing </body> tag.
function optimizeYouTubeEmbeds() {
    // Get all iframes
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );

    // Loop through each iframe in the page.
    for ( var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++ ) {

        // Find out youtube embed iframes.
        if ( frames[ i ].src && frames[ i ].src.length > 0 && frames[ i ].src.match(/http(s)?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com/)) {

            // For Youtube iframe, extract src and id.
            var src=frames[i].src;
            var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
            var id=(src.match(p) ? RegExp.$1 : false);
            if(id == false) { continue;}

            // Get width and height.
            var w=frames[i].width;
            var h=frames[i].height;
            if(src == '' || w=='' || h=='') {continue;}

            if ( $(window).width() > 700) { 
            // Thease are to position the play button centrally.
            var pw=Math.ceil(w/2-38.5);
            var ph=Math.ceil(h/2+38.5);    

            // The image+button overlay code.

           var code='<div alt="For this Google+ like YouTube trick, please see http://www.skipser.com/510" style="width:'+w+'px; height:'+h+'px; margin:0 auto"><a href="#"  onclick="LoadYoutubeVidOnPreviewClick(\''+id+'\','+w+','+h+');return false;" id="skipser-youtubevid-'+id+'"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/'+id+'/hqdefault.jpg" style="width:'+w+'px; height:'+h+'px;" /><div style="background: url(\'data:image/png;base64,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\') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;height: 77px;width: 77px; position:relative; margin-left:'+pw+'px; margin-top:-'+ph+'px;z-index:5;"></div></a></div>';

} 
else {
var pw=Math.ceil(w/7.5-1.5);
            var ph=Math.ceil(h/4.7+10);  
            var code='<div alt="For this Google+ like YouTube trick, please see http://www.skipser.com/510" style="max-width:100%;height:auto; margin:0 auto"><a href="#"  onclick="LoadYoutubeVidOnPreviewClick(\''+id+'\','+w+','+h+');return false;" id="skipser-youtubevid-'+id+'"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/'+id+'/hqdefault.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />  <div style="background: url(\'data:image/png;base64,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\') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;height: 77px;width: 77px; position:relative; margin-left:'+pw+'px; margin-top:-'+ph+'px;z-index:5;"></div><br><br><br></a></div>';

}

 // Replace the iframe with a the image+button code.
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML=code;
            div=div.firstChild;
            frames[i].parentNode.replaceChild(div, frames[i]);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
// Replace preview image of a video with it's iframe.
function LoadYoutubeVidOnPreviewClick(id,w ,h) {
    var code='<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+id+'/?autoplay=1&autohide=1&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1" width="'+w+'" height="'+h+'" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen style="border:1px solid #ccc;" ></iframe>';
    var iframe = document.createElement('div');
    iframe.innerHTML=code;
    iframe=iframe.firstChild;
    var div=document.getElementById("skipser-youtubevid-"+id);
    div.parentNode.replaceChild( iframe, div)
}
```

I've implemented the code here (it's my website) http://www.veryslowpc.com/security-measures.html
The outcome: in order to reduce page load times, embedded video iframes don't load until the user clicks on them, and the thumbnails are within page width when viewed on mobile.

Thank you for suggestions.

EDIT: The code should display the play button now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand

```
if ( $(window).width() > 700) {      
  //added the content of gplus-youtubeembed.js here
} 
else {
  //added the content of gplus-youtubeembed-mobile.js here
}
```

works only when a window is first loaded or refreshed. Try changing the size of your window and refresh your page. If the code works, you'll need something to reload the script or the page on resize.

Something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // add the stuff here to execute the your slider again;
});
```

or this might do the trick:

```
<script>
function refresh() { location.reload(); }
</script>

<body onresize="refresh()">
```

I'm no expert but I had similar issue just a few minutes ago. Hope I helped.

Comment: I did resize the window and refreshed it but there was no difference.

Could you please provide more detailes on how to use the second piece of code in your post ?

The third code in your post made no difference for desktop(thumbnails are small which means mobile JS was executed) but on mobile version the page goes into an infinite refresh loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little more detail on the second code that you asked for.

I'm only sharing with you what I'm learning as I go. I'm a real noob. Having the same problem as you but with a different snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('resize', function(){   
    if ($(window).width() > 700) {   
      // code here 
    } esle {   
      // code here 
    }
}); 
});
```

But you said refreshing your page didn't make the JS run. Which means this method might not help you. Have you checked to make sure both JS run and work regardless of page width? Maybe test each JS individually to make sure the mobile version is good.

Sorry if I can't be much help to you. I'm learning as I try to solve my own issues. Thought yours was close to the issue I was having.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.Unfortunately that didn't work.None of the JS executed when I use that method,so desktop and mobile visitor loads iframe instead of thumbnail.Both JS files work as intended when I use them individually.